# How can I create dynamic variable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I create dynamic variable in Flutter, I am Using ListView.builder and say itemCount is 3 (which can be dynamic) and so to store value From Dropdown I need dynamic variable One Option I have (may be I didn't check because of its complexity) is to make a Map then make a Class then ....
I want to make it simpler So how can I make it
(I think key can be used but I don't know how to Use it) so Please Help

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: shopCatList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
          print('listview fr ${shopCatList[i]}');
          tagItem = cate.cateProp[shopCatList[i]].tags;
          brandItem = cate.cateProp[shopCatList[i]].brand;
          // String k = shopCatList[i];
          String _selectedTag;
          String _selectedBrand;
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Card(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: Text(shopCatList[i],
                            style: Theme.of(context)
                                .textTheme
                                .headline6
                                .copyWith(color: CustomColors.BlueDark)),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 150,
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: DropdownButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
                              isExpanded: true,
                              hint: Text(_selectedTag ?? 'Select Tags'),
                              value: _selectedTag,
                              items: tagItem.map((valueItem) {
                                return DropdownMenuItem(
                                  value: valueItem,
                                  child: Text(valueItem),
                                );
                              }).toList(),
                              onChanged: (newValue) {
                                setState(() {
                                  _selectedTag = newValue;
                                  print('onSelect $_selectedTag');
                                });
                              }),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by create a dynamic variable

Comment: In the above code _selectedTag is variable defined in StateFul widget of which ListView.builder is a child Now here ItemCount is 3(say) so when i choose a dropdown value  hint of dropdown value got changed for every returning widget mean(for all itemCount) of listview.builder which give me error so i want variable number of _selectedTag like(_selectedTag1 ,_selectedTag2, _selectedTag3 ) so that i could put value of_selectedTag[i] = newValue;

Comment: In simple i want to declear variable as  _selectedTag0 ,_selectedTag1 ... like this number of variable which will be dynamic means the integer value can be 2, 5 ,8 dynamic number so this much of variable need to be decleared

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I have understood your means correctly, however, if you want to have multiple class format as an input for listView (or any other widget), you should use a parent class (or interface) as a wrapper! Then define it as an input for that specific widget. Now, for each other classes, you can extend the parent class. So, follow these steps:
step 1: define a parent class

```
class ParentClass {
}
```

step 2: define it as an input for your specific widget by constructor:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  
  ParentClass input;

  MyWidget(this.input);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: const Color(0xFF2DBD3A));
  }
}
```

3. extend parent class for every class you want!

```
class MyClass1 extends ParentClass{
   // variables.
}
```